# how do i align my th text in a same line

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svd7Q.png)in html i tried lots of th and text-align methods but i m not getting the expected results 
I want my heading tag to be displayed like the image

```css
table#tbl {
 valign : top;
 table-layout:fixed;
 word-wrap : break-word;
 text-align:right;
 
}
```

```html
<table  border="2px" style="width:100%;margin-top:8px;" id="tbl">
   <tr>
     <th width="3%">Sr no.</th>
     <th style="text-align:left" width="25%" >Item</th>
  <th width="15%">HSN</th>
  <th width="5%">Qty</th>
  <th width="10%">Rate/ Item</th>
  <th width="10%">Discount/ Item</th>
  <th width="10%">Taxable Value</th>
  <th width="8%">SGST</th>
  <th width="8%">CGST</th>
  <th width="12%">Total</th>
   </tr>
```

```css
table#tbl {
 valign : top;
 table-layout:fixed;
 word-wrap : break-word;
 text-align:right;
 
}
```

[image]

Comment: where is the image??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `vertical-align` on the `th` elements. You can do that using the descendent selector like this:

```
table#tbl th {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
table#tbl{ 
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: right;
}

table#tbl th {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table border="2px" style="width:100%;margin-top:8px;" id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <th width="3%">Sr no.</th>
    <th style="text-align:left" width="25%">Item</th>
    <th width="15%">HSN</th>
    <th width="5%">Qty</th>
    <th width="10%">Rate/ Item</th>
    <th width="10%">Discount/ Item</th>
    <th width="10%">Taxable Value</th>
    <th width="8%">SGST</th>
    <th width="8%">CGST</th>
    <th width="12%">Total</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept my answer if it solves your problem. Also do read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)